# How to read values assigned inside a script, in a program that runs that script?

Tags: perl, ipc, data-transfer

I need some help with reading value assigned inside sub scripts executed within main script in perl

1. I have "main.pl" where i have few hashes (`%var1` `%var2`) declared and assigned and am processing the values throughout the script.
2. Within main.pl, i execute a perl script "sub_scirpt.pl" using `system(perl sub_script.pl)`
3. Inside sub.pl, if i am assigning few value to `%var1`    `%var2`
4. How do i print the values assigned in sub_script.pl of `%var1` at main.pl script level?

Hope the above description gives some picture on my requirement.

content of sub_script.pl

```
our %var1 ; 
our $var1 = "start";
our $var2 = "abcd";
our $var3 = "efgh";
our @var4 = qw{test1 test2 test3};

$var1{$var2}{$var3}->{test1} = "1234";
$var1{$var2}{$var3}->{test2} = "5679";
$var1{$var2}{$var3}->{test3} = "5555";

foreach $var (@var4) {
    print "sub_script:: var1: $var1 \nsub_script:: var2: $var2  \nsub_script:: var3: $var3 \nsub_script:: var4: $var   \nsub_script:: hash-value: $var1{$var2}{$var3}->{$var}\n";
}
```

Output of sub_script.pl:

```
sub_script:: var1: start 
sub_script:: var2: abcd  
sub_script:: var3: efgh 
sub_script:: var4: test1   
sub_script:: hash-value: 1234
sub_script:: var1: start 
sub_script:: var2: abcd  
sub_script:: var3: efgh 
sub_script:: var4: test2   
sub_script:: hash-value: 5679
sub_script:: var1: start 
sub_script:: var2: abcd  
sub_script:: var3: efgh 
sub_script:: var4: test3   
sub_script:: hash-value: 5555
```

content of main.pl

```
@var1 = qw{start end};
$var1 = @var1[1];
our $var2  = "abcd";
our $var3  = "efgh";
@var4 = qw{test1 test2 test3};

system ("perl sub_script.pl");

print "\n\n";
foreach $var (@var4) {
    print "main:: var1: $var1 \nmain:: var2: $var2  \nmain:: var3: $var3 \nmain:: var4: $var   \nmain::hash-value:$var1{$var2}{$var3}->{$var}\n";
}
```

Output of main.pl:

```
main:: var1: end 
main:: var2: abcd  
main:: var3: efgh 
main:: var4: test1   
main:: hash-value:
main:: var1: end 
main:: var2: abcd  
main:: var3: efgh 
main:: var4: test2   
main:: hash-value:
main:: var1: end 
main:: var2: abcd  
main:: var3: efgh 
main:: var4: test3   
main:: hash-value:
```

Intended output:

```
main:: var1: start 
main:: var2: abcd  
main:: var3: efgh 
main:: var4: test1   
main:: hash-value: 1234
main:: var1: start 
main:: var2: abcd  
main:: var3: efgh 
main:: var4: test2   
main:: hash-value: 5679
main:: var1: start 
main:: var2: abcd  
main:: var3: efgh 
main:: var4: test3   
main:: hash-value: 5555
```

-Thanks in advance

Comment: Important: please provide code, instead of a description which is very difficult to work with. (Isn't it also easier?)  In short: you start and run a separate program (`sub.pl`), and what happens in it is completely separate from the "main" script.  So that program needs to pass the data back to the "main" script, and there is a number of ways to do so. But we need to see more of what you are doing and how, to be able to say more

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Shareable

Comment: @zdim My bad, should have included it at first place, didnt know how to update in comment, so edited the main post with more details.  Hope its much clear now.

Comment: Why do you run two scripts in separate processes? Can't you just have one script and `use` the other?

Comment: @Robert,  i just showed this small snippet as an example to have the issue explained better, actual script does few more processing inside sub_script.pl, which i dont want to clutter main.pl (some 500line code to process few logfiles) with,  and i just want the few subset of values to be used in main.pl

Comment: Alright! Thank you for upodating :)  So ... you expect the "main" program to show what the other program has?  It can't do that just so.  The other program is a thing in its own right, completely separate and independent.  But they can pass data between each other, and there are simple ways and then not-so-simple ones, depending on what you need.

Comment: If you want `sub_script.pl` to pass back (to "main") just simple values then it can even just print them, in a known order, and the "main" can call it using backticks (instead of `system`), which return to the program what the other program prints. So "main" says: `my @ret = qx(sub_script.pl);` and `@ret` has an element for each line that `sub_script.pl` prints.

Comment: But, if you want "sub" script to return a hash then it's more complicated, since there's keys and values and references -- you'd need to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the hash, so that it can be meaningfully sent byte by byte. One way is to have "sub" script write a file, for example using `Storable`, which "main" reads.  Can you clarify what exactly you actually need?

Comment: See [Storable](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html).  And let us know what _exactly_ you need to pass back to main (if that is knowable) as there may be yet other good ways

Comment: @zdim thanks for the options you proposed.  there is other assignments that happen to the hash inside "sub_script.pl" out of which i just need few assignments, also dont want to do the printing task inside the "sub_script.pl", but want to use the required data only at main.pl script.

Comment: The complicated way of writing the data to file and reading it in main file might be a workaround that can work, but there are lot more instantiations of "sub_script.pl" not sure if want to do the same for every time i call "sub_script.pl".

Comment: I was expecting more like creating variable scope global to be used across the main.pl and sub_script.pl, but if there is no such way to do, might have to see how writing to a file and reading would need to be integrated to main.pl. Hope i have not created more uncertainty with my explanation.

Comment: Alright, I get it.  A nice option would be to turn `sub_script.pl` into a module -- is that possible?  Then the `main.pl` can just `use` it, and call subroutines that return values and variables, etc.  Easy.  But if `sub_script.pl` needs to be a separate _program_ then you can't have it so that `main.pl` just sees its variables.  The data structures need be somehow "serialized" and passed.  One way is Storable, but with what you've explained the `sub_script.pl` can also make it into JSON, print that, and `main.pl` can pick it and turn it back into Perl data structure.

Comment: Thanks @zdim, i need to have sub_script.pl as separate program,  will try out JSON approach. Thanks again for your help in guidance with this.

Comment: Thought so -- posted a bare-bones example with JSON and Storable (but no need to write to files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you need to pass data from a program back to the program that invoked it.

If the called program (`sub_script.pl`) needs to return only simple values then it can just print them to `STDOUT`, where the calling program (`main.pl`)  runs it via "backticks" ([qx](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) in the operator form), which returns the program's `STDOUT`.

However, more complex data structures need be [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) so that they can be meaningfully sent down a pipe (of some kind) byte by byte.  There are various ways to do so, with good libraries, and simple code below demonstrates  two of them.

The [JSON format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is very simple, human readable, and accessible from any language and system. Perl libraries for conversion between Perl data structures and corresponding JSON are very simple to use.  This is a good and safe solution for a wide range of situations.

Perl's [Storable](https://perldoc.perl.org/Storable.html) is a tool for persistency, so that complex data structures can be dumped to disk and later restored from the file. One can also serialize data to strings that can be passed between programs with no need for files.

The program **sub_script.pl** below creates a hash and makes a `JSON` string out of it and prints it, and then also serializes the hash into a `Storable` string which it also prints

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use Storable qw(nfreeze);

my %h = (a => { A => 1}, b => { B => 2 }); 

my $str_json = encode_json \%h;
say $str_json;

my $str_st = nfreeze \%h;
say $str_st;
```

The following program (**main.pl**) runs the `sub_script.pl` above using `qx` so that it receives its `STDOUT`, and then it rebuilds the hash from both the `JSON` and `Storable` strings. In both cases we get back a hashref, a reference to data like the original hash

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use JSON;
use Storable qw(thaw);

use Data::Dump qw(dd);

my @ret = qx( sub_script.pl );
chomp @ret;

my $hr1 = decode_json $ret[0];
dd $hr1;

my $hr2 = thaw $ret[1];
dd $hr2;
```

I use [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) for simplicity, which will use the fast `JSON_XS` if installed, or the pure-Perl fallback, the core `JSON_PP`.  Another option is [Cpanel::JSON::XS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Cpanel::JSON::XS), a fork of `JSON_XS`.

To print complex data structures so to see them easily I use [Data::Dump](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dump), which probably need be installed. There is a number of other good modules to show complex data, the most widely used one being the core [Data::Dumper](https://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) (so no need to install).

---

In all of this, the program that is called still just prints to its `STDOUT`.  When data exchange needs get more complex you may need to use some "Inter-Process-Communication" ([IPC](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)) techniques.