# Return array value from one Perl script to another Perl script

Tags: arrays, perl

I have 2 scripts, say main_script.pl and secondary_script.pl

First I am running the `main_script.pl` which calls `seconday_script.pl`.

Code looks below for main_script.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var1 = "val_1";
my $var2 = "val_2";

my $sec_script = "/home/shared/Vinod/Perl_Test/secondary_script.pl";
my $result = `perl $sec_script $var1 $var2`;

print "Result:$result\n";
```

secondary_script.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $arg1 = $ARGV[0];
my $arg2 = $ARGV[1];

....
....
# DO SOME OPEARTION BY USING THE ARGUMENTS PASSED FROM main_script.pl
# FINALLY CREATE AN ARRAY @data

print Dumper(\@data);
```

Here I can able to generate output in array `@data`. But how can I pass this `@data` values to `main_script.pl` so that it will get stored in `result`.

Since in `main_script.pl` I have declared result as an `scalar` variable. My data value from `secondary_script.pl` would be `array`, so should I make result as an `array variable`? and how can I capture the data in `main_script.pl`?

Comment: Curiously, just a couple of days ago I answered a question quite like that, in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62242517/4653379)

Comment: @zdim this is much useful answer like Dave's answer.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that and thank you :)   That's why I dropped the link, hoping it may come useful

Answer (score 6):

In the secondary script, you can join the values with a known seperator, say |. In het main script you can split the string you receive on that seperator to get your array.

To give an idea how that could work:

```
use Data::Dumper;

my @arr = ("1", "3", "", "5");    
my $result = join ('|', @arr);   # in secondary script. print to stdout 
print STDERR Dumper(split( /\|/, $result));  # in main script: undo join
```

There is an edge case: if the first or last string of the array is an empty string, it will get lost and you have to do some extra tricks to account for that.

Answer (score 5):

First, I suggest asking yourself why you're doing this. Do they really need to be two separate programs? Could one, perhaps, become a module which you can then load in the other?

Maybe there are good reasons for doing it like this. Personally, I doubt it.

But, assuming you decide that you need to do it how you're currently doing it, then we need to talk about "serialisation" and "deserialisation". Serialisation is the act of taking a complex internal data structure and turning it into a representation (often a string) which can be safely passed outside of your program. Deserialisation is the opposite - you take the external representation and turn it back into a data structure.

So in your secondary script you need a subroutine called `serialise()` that you call like this:

```
print serialise(@data);
```

And in your main script, you can have:

```
my @result_array = deserialise(`... your call ...`);
```

You have several options for (de)serialisation. You could make your own (de)serialiser using Perl built-ins like `join()` and `split()`.

```
# This assumes you're sure that your array elements won't contain ':'.
# If that's a problem, then choose a different character.
sub serialise {
  return join ':', @_;
}

sub deserialise {
  return split /:/, $_[0];
}
```

You could use `freeze()` and `thaw()` subroutines from the standard [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) library:

```
use Storable qw[freeze thaw];

# Note that freeze() takes a reference and thaw() returns a reference.
sub serialise {
  return freeze($_[0]);
}

sub deserialise {
  return thaw($_[0]);
}
```

But I think the approach I would take would be to use a human-readable serialisation format like [YAML](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML) or [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON).

Comment: I strongly agree to your logic to make secondary script as an package.

Answer (score 5):

In the first script, output one element per line:

```
print join "\n", @data;
```

Then, read from backticks in list context to get one output line per element, then remove the line separator:

```
my @array = `...`;
chomp( @array );
```

If a newline is significant, use some other separator (I tend to like form feeds).

But, instead of that, perhaps consider something along the [modulino](https://www.drdobbs.com/scripts-as-modules/184416165) design where the data-generating program can act as both a module and a program. When another program needs it, it can load it as a module and call the right subroutine. No second program needed.

Beyond that, there are various interchange formats that might be appropriate. The particular modules I link to in this list may not be suitable for every task:

- [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable)
- [YAML](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::XS)
- [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::JSON)
- [Sereal](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sereal)
- many other things (binary JSON, msgpack, whatever)

Note that it's not always appropriate to reach for these formats right away. There's a cost associated with marshaling and unmarshalling the data. [Profiling the hidden costs of JSON and HTTP(S)](https://medium.com/@giuseppemaggiore/profiling-the-hidden-costs-of-json-and-http-s-c8f327d5db89) is an interesting read.

I'd tend to optimize for the "most friendly" output. The output format you choose decides how much pain the other side has to feel. My facile idea of simply printing to standard output means that everyone else has to treat your output as special. Maybe JSON fits in with what they're already doing elsewhere.

Or, you can output whatever they like. Have a way to do line-oriented output, JSON, XML, or whatever. Coming up with a way to do any format you choose means that you can easily add another format.